# Facebook Connect and Photo Albums

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Connect and Photo Albums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314571/facebook-connect-and-photo-albums)

I am developing a site for models and they will be able to upload pictures.

I want to know is it possible to use Facebook Connect to get the user's photo albums, to save the user from re-uploading all the photo's that are already on FB?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. The process would look something like this -

- prompt facebook connect / permission popup
- on successful login, facebook gives you a user id and an access token
- using that id and token (big string of numbers and letters) you can formulate a request the user's photos
- loop through the result of that request, pulling out each photo URL and caption or whatever
- use some kind of server-side language to save those photos somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger challenge is how check if particular picture matches another one from the album? If you know solution to this problem then running FQL on [`photo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo) and [`album`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album) tables should provide all the info about photos.

Comment: That's not the answer I'm after. I want to know if Facebook Connect allows you to access user's photo albums?

Comment: @GSTAR which part of the answer you don't like? Have you tried using FQL to read data from those two tables?

Comment: No, I haven't got that far yet. I'm still in planning stages, which is why I'm try to ascertain what I can and can't do. I assume it is possible to do, so my next question is, do I / should I link to these photos, or fetch them from Facebook and save a copy on my server?

Comment: re:the bigger challenge, do you mean duplicate photos among the ones pulled from facebook, or duplicates between the facebook ones and some others you already have?