# Facebook Connect and Photo Albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am currently developing a site for models/actors, and at this point I am just trying to ascertain what I can and can't do with Facebook Connect (I have virtually no experience in using Facebook Connect or FQL).

Basically there is going to be a facility whereby users will be able to upload their pictures. I want to know is it possible to use Facebook Connect to get the user's photo albums, in order to save the user from re-uploading all the photo's that are already on FB?

If so, do I/should I LINK to these photos, or FETCH them from Facebook and save a copy on my server?

EDIT: Just to clarify, this is what I want to do:

1. User will register on my site and agree to associate their Facebook ID with my site.
2. I then want to present the user with a list of all their albums that are on Facebook, the user can then select which albums they want to display on my site.
3. (optional) The user can select which specific photos in each album they want to display on my site.

Is this possible to do at all?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431229/facebook-connect-and-photo-albums (now closed)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload photos using the API. Check out this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo

If it were me, I would just upload the photo to Facebook and save the URL of the image rather than store it on my own server. You could do either one, but I don't see the sense is storing the image twice. The one issue could be if you wanted your photo at a higher quality than Facebook allows, but their quality is pretty high.

Comment: Well I'm not planning on uploading any photos to Facebook - it's more about retrieving user's existing photo's on Facebook. So assume I just link to these photos, what happens if the user deletes a photo from their album on Facebook? Or deletes a whole album? How can I handle these kind of situations?